# Max or Min of Consecutive Same Condition Match Excel or VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

[Max or Min For Consecutive Matching Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIVEl.png)

Dear Folks,

I am seeking help for the following roadblock in excel.

I am looking for a solution to find max/min if the conditions match for consecutive cells Please refer image above.

I can do it manually but the data rows runs in thousands, looking to find a way to get it done through formula in excel or VBA

Thank you all for helping out.

Comment: Thanks a Bunch, your solution did the trick, for which i had spent a day!

Comment: In that case, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming column `D` only has values "DN" and "UP", then the "Values" column, column `E`, won't contain the null string ("") implied by the formula quoted for column `E` (presumably cell `E3`) in the picture.

In this case, the formula for the "High.Low" column, Column `F` (not `G` as stated in the picture), can be implemented by the following:

cell `F2`: `=E2`
cell `F3`: `=IF(D2<>D3,E3,IF(D3="UP",MAX(F2,E3),MIN(F2,E3)))`

and copying cell `F3` to the range of cells below it.